# Both Observable.concat and Observable.forkjoin are not firing - Ionic 3 with Angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular2-observables

In Ionic, I am trying to call API in loop to upload off-line data to server. Both `Observable.concat` and `Observable.forkjoin` are not firing, not even prints "Inside Observable".

```
1. GetUnSyncTransFromLocal => gets the master data from SQLite
2. GetOrderDetailByOrNo => gets the details of that master from SQLite
3. SaveOrder => calls the service
```

The off-line data returned by first two methods are used to construct the object `CompleteOrder`

```
export class CompleteOrder {
    OrderMaster: OrderMaster;
    OrderDetails: OrderDetail[];
}
```

Then it uploads the order one by one.

```
let obserArray = [];
this.kbDb.GetUnSyncTransFromLocal(this.loginid).then(oData => {
      if (oData != undefined && oData.length > 0) {
        for (var so = 0; so < oData.length; so++) {
          this.orderToUpload = new CompleteOrder();
          this.orderToUpload.OrderMaster = oData[so];
          let _orNo = this.orderToUpload.OrderMaster.OrderNumber;
          this.kbDb.GetOrderDetailByOrNo(_orNo).then(dData => {
            if (dData != undefined && dData.length > 0) {
              this.orderToUpload.OrderDetails = dData;
              obserArray.push(Observable.of(this.syncService.SaveOrder(this.orderToUpload)));
            }
        }, aErr => {
            this.salesStatus.push({ UploadMsg: 'Cannot retrieve details for ' + _orNo + ' : ' + aErr });
        });
    }
    Observable.concat(obserArray).subscribe(dataArray => {
        console.log("Inside Observable");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
    }, err => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
```

Please advice me on what I am missing or any other approach to call API in loop.

Comment: Do you get any error? Lets you try  Observable.concat(...obserArray)

Comment: It is not throwing any error. It just skips the Observable block.

Comment: @SaravananSachi What do you want to achieve with the `obserArray`? Your `SaveOrder` function is not async anyway...